AttributeError: __aenter__ in async SQLalchemy sessions
I get AttributeError: __aenter__ error using session like this:
    async def get_session():
        SessionLocal = sessionmaker(
            autocommit=False,
            autoflush=False,
            bind=engine,
            expire_on_commit=False,
            class_=AsyncSession,
        )

        async with SessionLocal() as session:
            yield session

    async def insert(data_array):
        async with get_session() as session:
            session.add_all(data_array)
            await session.commit()

    await insert(reports)

error occurs here async with get_session() as _session:
in debugger get_session() is generator as it supposed to be, i guess, but no __aenter__ attribute inside
I am using asyncio, connected database is postgres
My sqlalchemy version is 2.0.28
I have tried some changes in sessionmaker but it didn't give any results

You should use async_sessionmaker instead of sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker

Also, add asynccontextmanager decorator to get_session
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

@asynccontextmanager
async def get_session():

So, your code example should be modified like this:
    @asynccontextmanager
    async def get_session():
        SessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(
            autocommit=False,
            autoflush=False,
            bind=engine,
            expire_on_commit=False,
            class_=AsyncSession,
        )

        async with SessionLocal() as session:
            yield session

    async def insert(data_array):
        async with get_session() as session:
            session.add_all(data_array)
            await session.commit()

    await insert(reports)


switched to async_sessionmaker, was already using create_async_engine, but it didn't make difference

Also, you don't need parenthesis after SessionLocal

and you need to add asynccontextmanager decorator to get_session

changing to async with SessionLocal as session:  gives the same error, but at this line

You right, it was my mistake.. I modified my answer
